# Illegal key size or default parameters with unlimited strength jars installed

Tags: java, macos, encryption, intellij-idea, javafx

I am using javafx to make a desktop app and it runs correctly when it is run through IntelliJ. When I build the artifact, the app no longer runs properly and throws `Illegal key size or default parameters`. Please note that I HAVE installed the unlimited strength cryptography jars into my jre/security folder. What else do I need to do in order to stop this issue from recurring?

Answer (score 2):

Chances are that you have actually not patched it correctly, or that you hit another jre than you think.

Try verifying if the jre have been patched, with something like:

```
System.out.println(Cipher.getMaxAllowedKeyLength("AES"));
```

My **unpatched** version gives: `128`, after **correctly patching** I would get `256`